# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow virtual virtual environment pip pipenv pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm, pipenv

I tried to create a new project with Pycharm with new Environment, using pipenv, but pycharm did not create one with error "CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a Win32 application".

After that, I deleted the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock and created Pycharm project with new environment, using virtualenv. Then I tried to install packages with "pip install pipenv" and "pipenv install *" and got error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow" tried to install tensorflow==2.2.0.

My python interpreter version is Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.

I don't understand what's wrong with me. When I created virtual environment with pipenv, everything worked with console, but did not work on Pycharm...

Answer (score 0):

Creating environments with pycharm is a headache. Better stick with the conslole commands, so you have compatibility.